# Enable full backtrace-logging in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debug-backtrace

I am getting an error only in production and to debug that, I would like to enable full backtracing in production.

I already have `config.log_level = :debug` in `config/environments/production.rb`, but that does not give me a backtrace, only logs the queries, requests and and served assets in detail.

Answer (score 0):

To show backtraces in the production environment, set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`. It's not good practice to leave this turned on, however it can be useful when provisioning a new production environment.